# (Python) regex: Match everything which is NOT in a (static) list of string

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have the (static) list `['DOG', 'CAT', 'LEOPARD']` (strings of possible different lengths).

I know how to construct the regular expression that catches pairs of comma-separated animals that belongs to this list:

```
from re import search
search('^(DOG|CAT|LEOPARD),(DOG|CAT|LEOPARD)$', 'DOG,LEOPARD') #-> Match
search('^(DOG|CAT|LEOPARD),(DOG|CAT|LEOPARD)$', 'LEOPARD,WHALE') #-> No match
```

I now want a regular expression that matches pairs of animal where none of them belong to my animal list. Using the dummy operator `!`, what I want is:

```
from re import search
search('^!(DOG|CAT|LEOPARD),!(DOG|CAT|LEOPARD)$', 'DOG,LEOPARD') #-> No match
search('^!(DOG|CAT|LEOPARD),!(DOG|CAT|LEOPARD)$', 'CHIMP,WHALE') #-> Match
```

Does such an operator exist ?

If not, is there a simple way to construct such an operator by chaining existing ones (I am writing a regular expression constructor, so neither readability nor length of the regex are important factors here) ?

**Note**: I am aware that I am asking a lot to my regular expression engine.

**Note 2**: I am not interested in solutions that do not rely on regular expression, as this problem integrates in a much larger one that I am already solving with (very complex) regular expressions.

Comment: If your question does not accurately represent the problem, it is not answerable. Please include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I believe I did. My questions is specifically about regex operators, not about solving this particular problem. The larger picture here is using regular expressions to match string representations of subgraphs; by constructing list of allowed or disabled node names. Whether or not this is optimal is a different question; and the specifics of my problem are in my opinion irrelevant. Please tell me if my question is inappropriate.

Comment: Your question, as it stands, is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), solvable with a much simpler method.

Comment: I do understand you concern. I guess the question is: can you trust that my bigger problem is not (solvable with a much simpler method); given my constraints ? I can expend on my constraints to make my problem more generable (for instance, I would need the answer to be able to compose nicely inside larger regex).

Comment: You have a programming challenge involving nodes and subgraphs and stuff ("X"). You have decided that it should be solved with regular expressions ("Y"), even though you are aware that it'll be messy at the very least. And now you are insisting that others try to solve Problem Y, without sharing more about Problem X, even though that information might allow someone to produce Solution Z which solves the problem in a much better way. That is why it is called the XY Problem rather than the XY Party or XY Perfect. :P I'm not trying to be difficult or anything - I want to see a solution for you.

Comment: Why not do a positive regex search and then negate your condition within the code?

Comment: @norbertpy Because I am matching multiple things at once in larger, composed regular-expression, so a boolean `NOT` would negate all of those.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing this using regex, you can use sets and test the intersection:

```
>>> a = set(['DOG', 'CAT', 'LEOPARD'])
>>> b = set('DOG,LEOPARD'.split(','))
>>> True if a.intersection(b) else False
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I added a second note explaining why I am only interested in regular expression-based solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use strings and built-in functions instead of regular expressions?

```
def matcher(no, s):
    return not any(word in no for word in set(s.split(',')))
```

Result:

```
>>> matcher({'DOG', 'CAT', 'LEOPARD'}, 'DOG,LEOPARD')
False
>>> matcher({'DOG', 'CAT', 'LEOPARD'}, 'CHIMP,WHALE')
True
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I added a second note explaining why I am only interested in regular expression-based solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!(?:DOG|CAT|LEOPARD),)[^,]+,(?!(?:DOG|CAT|LEOPARD)$)[^,]+$
```

Pattern breakdown:

```
^     assert position at start of string
(?!   assert the following text does NOT match...
    (?:DOG|CAT|LEOPARD) ...one of these 3 words...
    ,   ...followed by a comma. The comma is essential, because it makes sure that the text
           IS dog or cat or leopard. Without the comma, the regex would check if the text
           STARTS WITH dog, cat or leopard.
)
[^,]+   if we've reached this point, we know the animal isn't cat, dog or leopard. Match up
        until the next comma.
,       consume the comma
(?!     same as before, except this time...
    (?:DOG|CAT|LEOPARD)
    $   ...assert end of string instead of comma
)
[^,]+
$
```